# Modifying Django Form in template dynamically

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am displaying 100 objects from my DB in a page called channels.html

In one of the checkbox field called "is_new", I am able to retrieve data from DB for that specific row,

**channels.html**

```
{% for each_channel in channels_list %}
    .....
     ....... other elements.....

<td id="is_new">
**Attention here:{{form.is_new.value}} //--> I need to modify this **
```

**Manually am changing the checkbox values according to the value from DB. By writing HTML code by myself. It is working though,

    But I want it to be done dynamically in templates by accessing form.values, form.id, form.name and other html elements.**

```
// If the DB value is 1 then set the "yes" as checked and "No" as unchecked.  
// Set "Yes" as checked.

{% if each_channel.is_new%}
<span class="text-success" for="id_is_new_0">
<input id="id_is_new1_{{each_channel.usid}}" class="id_is_new"  name="is_new{{each_channel.usid}}" type="radio" value="1"checked="true"> Yes</span>

**// set "NO" unchecked**
<span for="id_is_new_1">
<input id="id_is_new0_{{each_channel.usid}}" class="id_is_new" name="is_new{{each_channel.usid}}" type="radio" value="0"> No</span>

*// Vice versa - If the DB value is 0, then do the vice versa.* 

{%else%}

**// Set "Yes" Unchecked.** 
<span for="id_is_new_0">
<input id="id_is_new1_{{each_channel.usid}}" class="id_is_new" name="is_new{{each_channel.usid}}" type="radio" value="1"> Yes</span>

**// Set "NO" Checked**
<span class="text-danger"  for="id_is_new_1">
<input id="id_is_new0_{{each_channel.usid}}" class="id_is_new" name="is_new{{each_channel.usid}}"type="radio" value="0" checked="True"> No</span>

{%endif%}
</td >
```

So in short, I dont want to use any 'default' or 'initial' in my Forms. I want dynamic values..

```
IF MY DB Value is THIS : 
Change my Form value, ID, Name to XXX

ELSE:
Change my Form value, ID, Name to YYY.
```

Can I do it in templates? Thanks.

Am using Django 1.5.

Comment: @GwynBleidD could you please see this.

Comment: @duffn, please check this

Comment: Can Someone answer this pl?